# How to get package name via an executable command name in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I know in CentOS/Fedora, I can find out package name via the following command:

```
dnf provides <executable name>
```

but what command in Ubuntu will do the same?

Comment: Here is a list of everything https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman/Rosetta

Comment: OK, and thank you! @Biswapriyo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you right,
You may want to know an exact package name on Ubuntu, you can use the `apt-cache` command to know the exact name of a package.

Open terminal and run:

```
sudo apt-cache search <executable-name>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I am looking for.